# Elasticsearch 5.5 getting error 'not_x_content_exception' using CURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch

I'm getting below error: while I trying to create mapping and its properties

```
Array
(
[error] => Array
    (
        [root_cause] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => not_x_content_exception
                        [reason] => Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
                    )

            )

        [type] => not_x_content_exception
        [reason] => Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
    )

[status] => 500
```

)

I'm Using CURL-here is my code using Codeigniter and elasticsearch

```
    $create ='
                {
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                      "type": "text"
                        }
                  }
                }
                ';
    $response = $this->elasticsearch->custome_function("_mapping/tweet","PUT", $create);
```

Here is my class file:

```
class ElasticSearch
{
public $index;
/**
 * constructor setting the config variables for server ip and index.
 */
   public function __construct()
   {
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci -> config -> load("elasticsearch");
    $this -> server = 'http://localhost:9200'; //$ci -> config -> item('es_server');
    $this -> index = "my_index";        // configured in constant file //$ci -> config -> item('index');
}

private function call($path, $method = 'GET', $data = null)
{
    if (!$this -> index) {
        throw new Exception('$this->index needs a value');
    }
    $url = $this -> server . '/' . $this -> index . '/' . $path;
    $headers = array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json', );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    switch($method) {
        case 'GET' :
            break;
        case 'POST' :
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case 'PUT' :
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            break;
        case 'DELETE' :
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
            break;
    }
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    return json_decode($response, true);
}


 public function custome_function($type,$method,$query)
 {
    return $this -> call($type,$method,$query);
 }
 }
```

Can anyone suggest me how to create mappings and properties or is there any alternate way to create mappings

Comment: Can you add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and provide the debug info that you see when executing?

Comment: I'm wondering if it may have something to do with calling `json_encode` on the already-JSON-formatted data that you're sending in: maybe that results in a document that the Elasticsearch API doesn't handle? Can you check to see what exactly you're getting after you encode it, or try removing that `json_encode` call in your `PUT` case?

Comment: Thank you dudes, after removing `json_encode` working fine

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I'm adding this as an answer, though the comments identified the problem.

According to an answer on this page (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/606), that error can happen when you send in a string rather than a JSON document.

Calling the `json_encode` in the PUT on a string that was already JSON-encoded resulted in sending in a non-JSON document to the Elasticsearch endpoint. Removing the unnecessary `json_encode` fixes the problem.